# Beautifulsoup - Collecting the href link and creating a list of links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im trying to collect all links within the list of guns (2 pages in this case) and print 1) the length and 2) the links themselves.

im getting the error:
list object has no attribute select

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

page = 1
all_links = []
url="https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page={}"

with requests.Session() as session:
  while True:
    print(url.format(page))
    res=session.get(url.format(page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    gun_details = soup.select('div.details')
    for link in gun_details.select('a'):
     all_links.append("https://www.gunstar.co.uk" + link['href'])
    if len(soup.select(".nav_next"))==0:
        break
    page += 1
```

If i remove the .content from the response i get response has no len.

if i add .text to the soup.select('div.details') i get similar result to above.

Im sure im going wrong somewhere fairly simple just cant seem to see it - is there a reason why select and findAll dont work when trying to hit a specific part of html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

page = 1

url="https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page={}"

with requests.Session() as session:
  while True:
    all_links=[]
    print(url.format(page))
    res=session.get(url.format(page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    gun_details = soup.select('div.details')
    for link in gun_details:
     all_links.append("https://www.gunstar.co.uk" + link.select_one('a')['href'])
    print(all_links)
    if len(soup.select(".nav_next"))==0:
        break
    page += 1
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page=1
['https://www.gunstar.co.uk/mauser-m96-lightning-hunter-straight-pull-270-rifles/rifles/1083802', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/magtech-586-12-bore-gauge-pump-action/Shotguns/1083784', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/merkel-kr1-bolt-action-308-rifles/rifles/1083786', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/christensen-arms-r93-carbon-bolt-action-7-mm-rifles/rifles/1083788', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/voere-lbw-luxus-bolt-action-308-rifles/rifles/1083792', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/voere-2155-bolt-action-243-rifles/rifles/1083797', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/voere-2155-2155-synthetic-bolt-action-308-rifles/rifles/1083798', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/mauser-m96-lightning-hunter-straight-pull-7-mm-rifles/rifles/1083799', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/blaser-lrs2-straight-pull-308-rifles/rifles/1084397', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/remington-700-s-s-barrel-only-bolt-action-300-win-mag-rifles/rifles/1084432']
https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page=2
['https://www.gunstar.co.uk/pfeiffer-waffen-handy-hunter-sr2-single-shot-300-win-mag-rif/rifles/1084433', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/sabatti-10-22-mod-sporter-semi-auto-22-rifles/rifles/1084442', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/voere-lbw-m-sniper-rifle-bolt-action-308-rifles/rifles/1084454', 'https://www.gunstar.co.uk/snipersystems-zoom-gun-light-kit-lamping/Accessories/1130763']
```

---

Another way of getting all links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

page = 1
all_links = []
url="https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page={}"

with requests.Session() as session:
  while True:

    print(url.format(page))
    res=session.get(url.format(page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    gun_details = soup.select('div.details > a')
    for link in gun_details:
     all_links.append("https://www.gunstar.co.uk" + link['href'])

    if len(soup.select(".nav_next"))==0:
        break
    page += 1

print(all_links)
```

Comment: Why are you calling the all_links twice? / what made you think to bring the all_links = [] into the while loop?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.Deleted.

Comment: That is just to show case  each parent url you are getting no of child links.If you want to get all child links then declare it in begging and remove from while list.Is that make sense.

Comment: aye see what youve done now.  was the for loop you added the select_one which sorted it out.  Fair play. righten sharp at this craic KunduK - im just messing about with it.  Interesting stuff like - python quite a powerful language - only started playing about with it last week.  Evolved one of your last helps into grabbing all the data from within those pages - gonna do the same with this one - interesting we tool.  Gonna see about downloading the images as well into separate folders for each advert will be the next step.

Comment: @AndrewGlass :Check another way of doing.

Comment: yeah both ways ive done so far are very similar - was the best method i could piece together from all the we pieces ive asked about - again only at it a week.  What others is there out there? anything youd recommend looking at?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the links from all the pages in different ways. Here is one of such to achieve the same using generators:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782"
base = "https://www.gunstar.co.uk"

def get_links(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for item in soup.select(".details > a"):
        yield urljoin(base,item['href'])

    next_page = soup.select_one(".gallery_navigation [rel='next']")
    if next_page:
        yield from get_links(next_page['href'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_links = [elem for elem in get_links(link)]
    print(list_of_links)
```

Comment: thats a nice clean method @SIM

Comment: clean indeed. As usual.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.